# Messages app showing unread number after deleted message. Can remove/reset?

Tags: messages

Just what the title says, I deleted a group message in Messages, but it's still showing the unread number from that thread (see screenshot) and *I can't bring up the group message because I deleted it*.

Short of having someone text in that group again to make it reappear, anyone know how I can fully delete the thread, or clear the unread number?

Comment: Did you try the old faithful "switch it off then back on again" ... Sign out, quit, launch, sign in.

Comment: I had tried that, and many other resets, but nothing has worked. Just started up my computer this morning and the unread number is gone, though. No idea why. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: I found [this answer][1] resolved the issue for me.


  [1]: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/why-does-messages-on-osx-always-show-unread-messages/155201#155201?newreg=141f13b8ff544a099e1cabb466fda6bc

Answer (score 7):

Two options:

1. Close Messages.app, then in the Terminal `killall Dock`. This worked for me.
2. Identify the message that Messages believes is unread (hover over icon in Dock) and delete it on your iDevice(s).

From here: http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/unread-messages-badge-on-mbp-is-stuck.1806575/

Also, this seems to be a duplicate of [Why does Messages on OSX always show unread messages?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125886/why-does-messages-on-osx-always-show-unread-messages)

Comment: The key is quitting Messages before "killAll Dock", otherwise, this might not work.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately so far the only way I have found to settle this problem is:

SHUT DOWN / HOLD SHIFT-CONTROL-COMMAND KEYS AND TURN COMPUTER BACK ON AND RELEASE RIGHT AWAY!

But that really isn't a FOREVER solution as it will happen again.  I wish there was a way to solve it without shutting down!